# Stitching Images in Bulk

Tags: image, photoshop, photoshop-script, panoramas, image-stitching

So I am doing this project where I am digitizing a bunch of old photo album pages. I am doing it as whole pages.

The problem is that some of the pages (over 100 of them) were too large to fit the scanner and had to be scanned in parts. I have been stitching them back together page by page manually in `photoshop` using the auto align image tool.

Is there a better software for access that or a way I could automate the process?

Comment: You can write a program to stitch images automatically. However this site isn't a job exchange for matching programmers to users.

Comment: Start in **Adobe Bridge**, select two or more files to be merged and then click `Tools->Photoshop->Photomerge` and it is quicker than dinking around in Photoshop itself.